# Как сделать предзагрузку аудио?

Tags: html5

Для вставки аудио используется следующий код:

```
$("<audio id='SoundLogo'>" + 
  "<source src='files/SoundLogo.ogg' type='audio/ogg'>" + 
  "<source src='files/SoundLogo.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>" + 
  "<source src='files/SoundLogo.wav' type='audio/wav'></audio>").appendTo("body");
```

Как сделать предзагрузку аудио, чтобы при его воспроизведении оно не тормозило?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос больше по html, чем по js.

Если вбить `audio html` в гугле, то по первой же ссылке будет описание возможных атрибутов. Среди которых значится `preload`, который достаточно просто добавить к тегу `<audio>` со значением `"auto"`, чтобы все заработало в нужно ключе.

Но возможно, имеет смысл задуматься, а нужно ли все пользователям прелодить аудио (у кого-то возможно инет медленный и так, а если аудио грузить, могут возникнуть дополнительные проблемы). Если же сервер не успевает нормально отдавать аудио, даже при хорошем соединении у клиента - нужно править сервер, а не клиент.